# KGroupedStream with cogroup, aggregate & suppress

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Trying to cogroup, aggregate & suppress streams which result in -

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.PassThrough cannot be cast to class org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KTableProcessorSupplier (org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.PassThrough and org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KTableProcessorSupplier are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

```
        val stream1 = requestStreams.merge(successStreams).merge(errorStreams)
                .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), serdesConfig.notificationSerde()))

        val streams2 = confirmationStreams
                .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), serdesConfig.confirmationsSerde()))

        val cogrouped = stream1.cogroup(notificationAggregator).cogroup(streams2, confirmationsAggregator)
                .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(notificationStreamsConfig.joinWindowMinutes.toLong())).grace(Duration.ofMinutes(notificationStreamsConfig.graceDurationMinutes.toLong())))
                .aggregate({ null }, Materialized.`as`<String, NotificationMetric, WindowStore<Bytes, ByteArray>>("time-windowed-aggregated-stream-store")
                        .withValueSerde(serdesConfig.notificationMetricSerde()))
                 .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(unbounded()))
                .toStream()
```

However, if I remove the `.suppress` it works fine.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. Can you please file a Jira ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA

Comment: Thank you, created - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-10417

Comment: This has been fixed in 2.7.1 and 2.8.0+